# Events collection dates are off on collection view

Tags: events, timezone, plone

I have a Plone site that was recently updated from Plone 3.1 to Plone 4.

We had an events folder that had a default view that showed a collection of events.  In that view, the start and end times are displayed.

Whenever I make a new event content type object and specify the times, the times are off by 8 hours early on the collection table, but correctly shows when I'm viewing the Event created.

Is there some setting that I have to set for the collection time to show properly?

I was looking into some older information searched about time zones, but it doesn't seem to have any effect when I run the buildout with this setting:

```
zope-conf-additional =
<environment>
      TZ America/New_York
</environment>
```

Am I missing anything else?  All the migrated content appear to show the correct times in the collection table.

Comment: Your claim is that event are being displayed inside a collection view with a different time than inside the event detail view?

Comment: @RestRisiko: It's a bug I have heard about before. Trying to turn a vague recollection into something more helpful atm.

Comment: Indeed, it looks to me as if we never did solve this.  It's a specifically Windows problem - my test site, using a copy of the Windows Data.fs on a Linux system has correct times.

Comment: I am running this instance on Redhat Linux and did not switch platforms.

Answer (score 2):

The collection display takes the dates from the catalog metadata *as strings* and interprets those as DateTime instances. The event edit form works with the actual DateTime instances. Clearly something goes wrong with the catalog storage of the start and end dates, and/or with the display.

You could check the timezone on your indexed events. Go to the ZMI, find the `portal_catalog` object, and navigate to it's `Catalog` tab. Find any `ATEvent` there (you can use the path filter to narrow down results), and click on it's hyperlinked path. It'll open a new window with the catalog information for that specific object. The top table holds the catalog metadata on that object, and collections will use the `start` and `end` fields to render event info. Note that these should include timezone info; in my test setup I see date-time strings like `2011/07/05 22:45:00 GMT+2`.

If these dates look off to you (missing or incorrect timezone), do a full reindex of your site. Use the `Advanced` tab of the `portal_catalog` object, there is a `Update Catalog` button there. I'd set the `Log progress of reindexing` value to 1000 objects or so so you get to see the progress in the Zope event log.

Comment: This did not change the event display in a collection.
It did however change date from "2010-10-26 10:25:00" to "2010-10-26T10:25:00-04:00" formats